# SwiftyJSON - Unable to Parse Json

Tags: json, swift, swift3, swifty-json

I am receiving the following JSON from an API call.

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "promotion" : {
    "insert_list" : [

    ],
    "remove_list" : [
      {
        "id" : "9"
      }
    ]
  },
  "message" : "Synchronized Successfully."
}
```

I want to process the `remove_list` by extracting individual id, here is the swift code, I am using.

```
Alamofire.request(requestURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let value):
        let response = JSON(value)
        print(response)
        if "success" == response["status"] {
            // Format Promotion Ids To Remove From List
            var promotionIdsToRemove:[Int32] = []
            for (_,promotionJson):(String, JSON) in response["promotion"]["remove_list"] {
                promotionIdsToRemove.append(promotionJson["id"].int32!)
            }   
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

This is throwing me an error saying, `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` pointing towards the following code `promotionIdsToRemove.append(promotionJson["id"].int32!)`

If I print just the `promotionJson["id"]` it gives me the correct value, but when I typecast it, throws me this error.

What may be the issue here?

Comment: did you try to print promotionJson["id"]?

Comment: Yes! and it prints the value 9, the problem is while type casting.

Comment: but it is a string, are you sure that swifty can just change anything to int32 that you force unwrap that?

Comment: You should try using `Int(promotionJson["id"])` if `promotionJson["id"]` is parsed as String.

Comment: @Lu_ yes it can. if you refer the documentation. I am also using it on other places. not sure what is happening in here. David let me try that as well.

Comment: @DávidPásztor If I try to do that I get the error `Cannot invoke initializer for type int with an argument list of type JSON`

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar as I've said, that `Int` initializer expects a `String` as an input argument, so you should first get a `String` from your `JSON` object.

Comment: @DávidPásztor thanks. It seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @DávidPásztor, following code seems to do the trick.

```
var promotionIdsToRemove:[Int32] = []
for (_,promotionJson):(String, JSON) in response["promotion"]["remove_list"] {
    promotionIdsToRemove.append(Int32(promotionJson["id"].string!)!)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to treat the `remove_list` as an array by telling SwiftyJSON to do so. Your code should be

```
for removeJSON in response["promotion"]["remove_list"].arrayValue {
    // removeJSON is of type JSON here
    promotionIdsToRemove.append(removeJSON["id"].intValue)
}
```

This will loop over the remove_list array and append all id's to `promotionIdsToRemove`. If an item doesn't have an id field, `.intValue` will make sure you get either the correct value or `0` for the id.

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: This still gives me the error. the Solution that I posted seems to be the only one that is working. It is strange though.

Comment: That's very strange... I've worked with SwiftyJSON a lot but never saw anything like what you're experiencing. Are you sure you copied my entire loop?

Comment: It is indeed very strange, I have been using SwiftyJSON since some time as well, and this is the first time, I am having the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

`response["promotion"]["remove_list"]` should be Array, not Dictionary.

change your code to

```
        for promotionJson in response["promotion"]["remove_list"] {
            promotionIdsToRemove.append(promotionJson["id"].int32!)
        }
```

Comment: This does not work. it gives me the error `"Type JSON._Element (aka (String, JSON)) has no subscript members."`